# mysql select increment group row number

Tags: mysql, query

i had a table like following:

```
OBJECTID            FRUIT
----------------------------
XA13AC              Apple
HAS13X              Grape
UTHQ1G              Orange
YQ1GXQ              Kiwi
OQP1GV              Apple
GPQ1VA              Grape
GQ1GQ1              Manggo
GYX1GQ              Banana
OPI1G2              Apple
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `FRUITS` (
  `OBJECTID` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FRUIT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Data:

```
insert into `FRUITS` (`OBJECTID`, `FRUIT`) values('XA13AC','Apple');
insert into `FRUITS` (`OBJECTID`, `FRUIT`) values('HAS13X','Grape');
insert into `FRUITS` (`OBJECTID`, `FRUIT`) values('UTHQ1G','Orange');
insert into `FRUITS` (`OBJECTID`, `FRUIT`) values('YQ1GXQ','Kiwi');
insert into `FRUITS` (`OBJECTID`, `FRUIT`) values('OQP1GV','Apple');
insert into `FRUITS` (`OBJECTID`, `FRUIT`) values('GPQ1VA','Grape');
insert into `FRUITS` (`OBJECTID`, `FRUIT`) values('GQ1GQ1','Manggo');
insert into `FRUITS` (`OBJECTID`, `FRUIT`) values('GYX1GQ','Banana');
insert into `FRUITS` (`OBJECTID`, `FRUIT`) values('OPI1G2','Apple');
```

i tried following SQL not working:

```
SELECT *,
             ( 
                CASE FRUIT 
                WHEN @curType 
                THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
                ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := FRUIT END
              ) + 1 AS GROUP_NUM
FROM FRUITS 
JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
GROUP BY FRUIT
```

expected result:

```
OBJECTID            FRUIT       GROUP_NUM
-----------------------------------------
XA13AC              Apple           1
HAS13X              Grape           2
UTHQ1G              Orange          3
YQ1GXQ              Kiwi            4
OQP1GV              Apple           1
GPQ1VA              Grape           2
GQ1GQ1              Manggo          5
GYX1GQ              Banana          6
OPI1G2              Apple           1
```

trying to group the fruit by name and its increment group_num on different fruit name.

any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Ordering needed. Try to add `ORDER BY fruit`.

Comment: the group_num not populated correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For version 5+

```
SELECT OBJECTID,
       CASE WHEN FRUIT = @curType 
            THEN @curRow 
            ELSE @curRow := @curRow + 1 END AS GROUP_NUM,
       @curType := FRUIT FRUIT
FROM FRUITS, (SELECT @curRow := 1, @curType := '') r
ORDER BY FRUIT
```

For version 8+

```
SELECT OBJECTID, FRUIT, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY FRUIT) GROUP_NUM
FROM FRUITS
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f277fb923534c7feea7a0a0d48c53449)